# Header not working PHP

Tags: php, redirect, safari, header

I am using MAMP, NetBeans to develop php website on my Mac. I wrote the following code but ran into error repeatedly. I tried all the commented lines but neither one works.

```
<?php
if ($output == 1) //Authenticated = yes
{

    $url = "http://www.google.com”;
    //error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
    //
    //  include('./dlheader.inc');

    //header("Content - Length: 0");
    // header("Location: http://google.com", true, 303);
    // header("Location:".$url);
    //  header("Location: http://google.com", true);
    //   exit;

    /*          flush();
          if (headers_sent()) {
die('cannot send location header (anymore)');
}
    else {
    header('Location: '.$url);
    die();
}

*/
    //echo '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=' . $url . '"/>;

}
?>
```

This code is exactly after the `<body>` tag. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This is a poorly asked question. To insure good responses you should include both the expected result ('I want to load google.com') and the actual result ('I got the following error message: blah blah blah')

Comment: what is the value of the $output variable? is it being locally declared or is it coming coming as a request variable? If $output does not have a value, your code will never be read in the if/else statment.

Comment: @LazyOne your edit might have blown away the actual problem with this code -  the curly quote at the end of google.com

Comment: @Michael True, I forgot to restore it after code reformat. As tiny excuse -- this issue was already spotted in answer and voted up quite few times. In any case -- I'll be more careful next time. Thnx for letting me know.

Answer (score 10):

If this is exactly your code, you need to fix this curly quote.  It looks like it was copy/pasted from a website or word processor.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com”;
                            ^^^^
```

Should be

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
```

Since it is not a proper double-quote, PHP does not see the string as being closed and all subsequent code is treated as part of the string until another `"` is encountered.

Answer (score 5):

If that space before the php tag is in your file then header() won't work. No white space or any sort of output can occur in a php file before the header(), or it won't work as headers will have already been sent.

You can check this with the boolean result from the function headers_sent():

```
if(headers_sent())
{
    echo "headers already sent!";
}
```

Comment: Unless output buffering is on.  But it usually isn't by default.  The question states that the code is after the body tag.  So the output mentioned in the answer above would be the opening html, head tags and opening body tag.